# bind different Knockout JS templates inside foreach loop

Tags: templates, binding, foreach, knockout.js

I am trying to use KO templates to parse a JSON file ([see here](http://pastebin.com/bUdZfn0X)) into some pretty looking grid layouts.. (think similar to masonry/isotope layouts).. each template section will have different sized rectangles and squares inside it but the overall template conforms to a grid of 5 boxes wide by 3 boxes high ([for example](http://smg.photobucket.com/albums/v521/haxxxton/?action=view&current=grid.png))

Given this what i have been trying to do is detect the template, then iterate through each item, if its a certain index in the iteration load either the single, double, or triple subtemplate..

my problem is that i cant seem to get it to check which key in the ViewTestProposal array im currently on..

below is my WIP code..

```
<div data-bind="template: {if: Template == 'basic2', visible: Template == 'basic2', foreach: ViewTestProposal}">
    <div data-bind="template: {if: ViewTestProposal[0], name: 'single'}"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="single">
    <div class="box single">
        <p data-bind="text: Artist, attr:{title: Artist}"></p>
    </div>
</script>
```

I have tried changing the `if: ViewTestProposal[0]` section to `with: ViewTestProposal[0]`,`if: ViewTestProposal() === 0` and `if: ViewTestProposal == 0` to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template name parameter can be a function that returns the name based on the current item in the array ([See note 4](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)). With this you could access a property on each item that has the template name:

```
<div data-bind="template: {
        foreach: ViewTestProposal, 
        name: function(item) {return item.boxsize;}
    }"></div>
```

If you need to use the index of the item in the array, this is available starting with Knockout version 2.1 through the `$index` [context property](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html). Starting with version 2.2 (not yet released [1/Oct/2012], but [release candidate version available](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/downloads)), the name function can also access the context object. Then you could do something like this:

```
<div data-bind="template: {
        foreach: ViewTestProposal, 
        name: function(item, context) {
            switch(context.$index()) {
            case 0:
                return 'single';
            case 1:
                return 'double';
            // etc.
            }
        }
    }"></div>
```

Obviously, the function itself could be defined in your view model.

Comment: sadly enough.. i just cracked it too.. thank you so much for the more information though! Much appreciated

Comment: I tried copy and pasting your code into the KO template and it doesnt seem to be outputting anything? could you offer anything more?

Comment: I forgot the `$` in `context.$index`. I've updated it now. If you're still having trouble, try checking your browser's console log for any errors.