# Knockout bind widgets array to specific template name

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind an array of widgets to custom templates using knockout.

Basically every widget has defined the templateToUse.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z4wgaovq/)

However when I try to bind every widget to template and call the `getTemplate` function I get `undefined` error.

I also set a function to be called afterRender which throws this error: `Error: Unable to get property 'nodeType' of undefined or null reference`.

What I am doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="row" data-bind="template: { name: getTemplate, foreach: { data: widgets, afterRender: $root.afterAddWidget }}">

</div>

<script type="text/html" id="panel-template">
    <div class="panel panel-color" data-bind="css: $data.panelType" id="demo-panel-network">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Green colored panel</h3>
            <div class="panel-control">
                <button class="btn" id="demo-panel-network-refresh" data-toggle="panel-overlay" data-target="#demo-panel-network"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="panel"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $root.delete_widget"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>fdgd</p>              
        </div>
    </div>

</script>
```

JS:

```
  $(function () {
        var ViewModel = function (widgets) {

            this.widgets = ko.observableArray(widgets);


            this.delete_widget = function (item) {

                self.widgets.remove(item);

            };

            this.getTemplate = function (item) {
                alert(item.templateToUse);
                return item.templateToUse;
            }


            this.afterAddWidget = function (items) {

                alert('after');


            };
        };

        var widgets = [
            { x: 0, y: 0, width: 6, height: 6, noResize: 'yes', noMove: 'no', autoposition: 'no', isLocked: 'no', panelType: 'panel-success', templateToUse: 'panel-template' },
            { x: 8, y: 0, width: 4, height: 2, noResize: 'yes', noMove: 'no', autoposition: 'no', isLocked: 'no', panelType: 'panel-warning', templateToUse: 'panel-template' },
            { x: 0, y: 8, width: 4, height: 2, noResize: 'yes', noMove: 'no', autoposition: 'no', isLocked: 'no', panelType: 'panel-info', templateToUse: 'panel-template' },
            { x: 4, y: 8, width: 4, height: 2, noResize: 'yes', noMove: 'no', autoposition: 'no', isLocked: 'no', panelType: 'panel-danger', templateToUse: 'panel-template' },
            { x: 8, y: 8, width: 4, height: 2, noResize: 'yes', noMove: 'no', autoposition: 'no', isLocked: 'no', panelType: 'panel-purple', templateToUse: 'panel-template' },

        ];

        var viewModel = new ViewModel(widgets);

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bind different Knockout JS templates inside foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687048/bind-different-knockout-js-templates-inside-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` is misplaced.  You want to bind the template foreach of the widgets.

```
<div class="row" data-bind="template: { name: getTemplate,
                                        foreach: widgets,
                                        afterRender: $root.afterAddWidget }"></div>
```

The way you have it set up, you're telling knockout to render your mapping as the items for the template.